# How to connect from react to google cloud storage and get private object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I am trying to connect with React to google cloud storage but I can't any suggestions. Basically, I want to view private objects from the bucket in google cloud storage directly from React.JS. Anyone, please help me how I get the private objects in the google cloud bucket from React.JS, Thanks

Comment: If you’re getting it via the Frontend, then it’s not private.

Comment: You have several options: 1) Use the Google Cloud Storage client libraries and **expose** your credentials to the browser. **Be careful that you understand what you are doing**. 2) Implement a backend that creates a signed URL for the client browser to access private objects. 3) Implement access at the backend and send the data to the client. 4) Start with this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs

Comment: Hi John Hanley, Thank you for your comment, i face a error when i install @google-cloud/storage plugin and import this in react frontend, i send this this error 
"TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function". If you have any idea please reply me

Comment: spend time to learn the SDK. Then post a question with https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Signed URLs would be the best fitting solution for the problem you are describing, but if it's not an option for other reasons I would say that you will have to create a backend endpoint that retrieves that image impersonating a Service Account which will have an access that does not expire.

In summary, you are going to have to choose were to are going to compromise, either creating extra calls to your backend or extra operations to retrieve new Signed URLs after 7 days.